# How to set a response to custom JOptionPane?

Tags: java, user-input, joptionpane

Say you have this JOptionPane:

```
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
    "Do you like this answer?", 
    "Feedback", 
    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
    null, 
    new String[]{"Yes I do", "No I don't"}, // this is the array
    "default");
```

How would you set an answer to this to display? For example, how would you call the "Yes I do" and how would you call the "No I don't" ? I'm just not sure how to make the buttons do what I want them to do.

Answer (score 1):

The option dialog return an int to determine what button have been pressed

```
int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
            "Do you like this answer?", 
            "Feedback", 
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
            null, 
            new String[]{"Yes I do", "No I don't"}, // this is the array
            "default");

    if(result == 0) { //0 is 'Yes I do' option
        //do stuff
    }
```

Comment: oh so it's saying "yes i do" is 0 and "no i don't" is 1?

Comment: @sab Yes it is, and 1 to another option.

Answer (score 1):

The static methods won't get you there. You will instead have to rely on the constructor with a similar parameter list:

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Do you like this answer?", OptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, null, new String[]{"Yes I do", "No I don't"},"default");
optionPane.setVisible(true);
optionPane.setInputValue("Yes I do");
```